# Query hint for insert from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I'm running SQL Server 2014.

In the following code, I have a temp table (defined earlier in code) that is being filled from a stored procedure. Most of the parameters for the stored procedure are standard data types, but `@GroupLayoutSpecifications` is a table variable that accepts a small heap table that is joined to within the stored procedure.

```
INSERT #StandardizedResponses
    EXEC rpt.usp_QueryBuilder_GatherStandardizedResponses
              @Member, @OrgUnits, @Groups, @MeasureName, 
              @StartDate, @EndDate, @InstrumentTypeIDs, 
              @BackgroundDataIDs, @GroupLayoutSpecifications;
```

The problem I'm having the query engine isn't able to effectively estimate the number of rows that the stored procedure is likely to return. It is typical for it to estimate a return of something like 1 row, with an actual return of closer to 200k rows. I believe this is what is causing a tempdb spillover later in the plan.

Is it likely that it is the table-type parameter that is causing the query engine some grief? If so, how might I get around that?

Similarly, is there a way to hint to SQL Server that the following query will likely result in a larger than expected row count?

I've researched this quite a bit through things like MSDN, this site, SQL Authority, and others, and am hoping someone here can help me tune this.

If you need more information to supply a reasonable answer, just let me know what you might need.

Cheers,

Joe

Comment: Use `option (recompile)` or trace flag 2453.

Comment: You might want to see if [trace flag 2453 helps](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/table-variable-perf-fix), though that is for table variables, I don't know if it improves estimates for TVPs. (But wait, are you really passing 200K rows through a TVP?)

Comment: To clarify, the tvp only ever receives a table with ten or so rows. The 200k rows is what is returned by the sproc.

Comment: option (recompile) isn't valid for insert, update, or delete statements.  It might work inside of the stored procedure, give it a try.  What is the procedure doing with the join that you need to abstract that logic away?

Comment: There are some good blog posts about the performance hit of the Insert Exec. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/06/25/the-hidden-costs-of-insert-exec.aspx http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2011/07/25/comparing-the-cost-of-insert-exec-and-its-alternatives.aspx
how long does the SP take to run by itself without the Insert vs with?

Comment: Great feedback. Thanks everybody. I think I will go a different route and pass the access via a permanent table rather than pass them in via a table variable. I think the optimizer will have an easier time with that and will be an easier pattern for the other devs to follow.